# Create a sequence of Animation on UIButton IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I am pretty new to IOS animation programming.
I wanna create an animation like this on an UIButton:

1. first scale up in 0.3 second,
2. then scale down back to normal in 0.2 second.

Can some one show me or guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Code :**

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.60 animations:^{
        myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.60 relativeDuration:0.40 animations:^{
        myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Completed");
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use native animation pulse in it.

```
var pulseAnimation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale");
        pulseAnimation.duration = 1.0;
        pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.5);
        pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut);
        pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true;
        pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
        self.Outlet.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)
```